# C# Security: check query string for valid .pdf filename

Tags: c#, validation, request.querystring

I'm modifying an .aspx page that uses some javascript to download a file based on the value attribute in this tag:

```
<input type="hidden" id="launchDocument" value="pdf/<%=Settings.LaunchDocument%>" >
```

That value is currently hard-coded into the Web.config file. The client wants this page to now be a download page for their archived newsletters. My thoughts were to have the page pull in the filename from the query string so the sending page could define what file is being downloaded:

```
<input type="hidden" id="launchDocument" value="../pdf/<%=Request.QueryString["filename"]%>" />
```

But, I'm concerned whether there is any security risk to this method. If there is, what are the best practices for checking the query string's value to make sure it's a valid .pdf filename before adding it to the page?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What's to stop someone from setting the querystring to "../../../../Windows/system32/config/SAM" and downloading your windows password file? Don't expose paths/filenames to the world. keep a list of files in a database and expose the file's database ID value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the forum search and you find this:

[Regular expressions in C# for file name validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100045/regular-expressions-in-c-for-file-name-validation)

Comment: While some of the other answers were perhaps better when it comes to security, this worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Why does the actual file name need to be there? Create a table that associates a filename with a guid and pass that around.

When it comes time to download, transfer to a script that loads and spits the file back.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to pass around GUIDs or similarly opaque identifiers, use something simpler. You could even just use the file name. As a bonus, this abstracts away the storage mechanism, meaning that you can move files around and the users won't ever know about it, much less be bothered by it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an HTTP handler to watch for these requests, and in the handler check if the file exists, and if it doesnt redirect to an appropriate error page...

Comment: If the file that exists is a sensitive file such as windows password file (as @Marc B shows above), then this check will pass.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use file extensions in the `<input>` field
2. Always append .PDF to the path supplied by the input.
3. Expand the relative path to an absolute path.
4. Validate the absolute path (check that it's in the PDF download dir)