# What characters are not allowed in Windows File Names and how can I restrict them from typing in C#

Tags: wpf, windows, c#-4.0, file-io, .net-4.0

I am trying to let the user save a file with a name entered in a `WPF` `Textbox` control. My Requirement is to *restrict* all the *characters* which are not allowed inside a `file/folder` name in Microsoft Windows OS.

Is there a `regex pattern` in `C#` to *not* allow typing such characters in a WPF Textbox and also give a `Beep` sound when such characters are typed and restricted, which I can apply on some event of WPF Textbox?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100045/regular-expressions-in-c-sharp-for-file-name-validation or write your own according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx), but be aware that the list is not necessarily exhaustive (see linked MSDN documentation).

For example, there are further restrictions for  [SharePoint filenames](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  you will find what you need to know about naming files and paths.

Then you can setup a [CustomValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182556%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)